# Angular populate input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input, populate

I have a object that gets populated via a restful API in my root scope and then in my child scope I'm trying to populate some input fields.

child controller

```
$scope.profileForm = $scope.$parent.student;
```

this works and I can

```
console.log($scope.profileForm.FirstName);
```

but the input on my page does not populate?

```
<input ng-model="profileForm.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-first" id="first-name-input" placeholder="FIRSTNAME" required />
```

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! :) i Had

```
<form name="profileForm" ... />
```

which messes up the scope variable, duh!